# Using Multiple Patterns in Form Field

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation, email

I'm attempting to create an email form field that requires a user to enter an email in the hello@domain.ext format but also only allowing business emails to come through (no gmail, yahoo, hotmail, ect.)

I've created 2 field patterns that work independently, but I can't seem to get them to work together.

Requires a hello@domain.ext format

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
```

Does not allow these free email domains. Business emails only.

```
pattern="^(?!.*@(?:live|gmx|yahoo|outlook|msn|icloud|facebook|aol|zoho|yandex|lycox|inbox|myway|aim|goowy|juno|(?:hot|[gy]|google|short|at|proton|hush|lycos|fast)?mail)\.\w+$).*$"
```

Here is my form code:

```
    <form  method="POST" action="#">

    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D70000000KCoG">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" 
    value="#">

    <label for="email">Email</label><input id="email" maxlength="80" 
    name="email" size="30" type="email" 
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter your business email here.')" 
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" pattern="[a-z0-
    9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: I ask out of curiosity - is there a difference between specifying `pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"` and specifying `type="email"`?

Comment: type="email" allows one to enter the email a@b, but pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" only allows emails in the hello@domain.ext format.

Comment: @Felicia Please check my answer below, and let know if it  works fine for you or you need more help.

Comment: Good to know, @FeliciaSantos - thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the two patterns combined:

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(?!(?:live|gmx|yahoo|outlook|msn|icloud|facebook|aol|zoho|yandex|lycox|inbox|myway|aim|goowy|juno|(?:hot|[gy]|google|short|at|proton|hush|lycos|fast)?mail)\.\w+$)[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
```

Note that the `^` at the start and `$` at the end are not necessary as they are implicit there: `pattern` value is wrapped with `^(?:` and `)$` to match the entire input value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV4Q5k/1).

**Details**

- `^`  - implicit - start of string
- `[a-z0-9._%+-]+` - one or more letters, digits, `.`, `_`, `%`, `+` or `-`
- `@` - a `@`
- `(?!(?:live|gmx|yahoo|outlook|msn|icloud|facebook|aol|zoho|yandex|lycox|inbox|myway|aim|goowy|juno|(?:hot|[gy]|google|short|at|proton|hush|lycos|fast)?mail)\.\w+$)` - a negative lookahead the fails the match if the pattern matches immediately to the right of the current location (that is, after `@`)
- `[a-z0-9.-]+` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `.` or/and `-`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-z]{2,4}` - 2 to 4 lowercase ASCII letters.

NOTE: you might want to add `A-Z` to the character classes: `[a-z0-9._%+-]+` => `[\w.%+-]+` and `[a-z0-9.-]+` => `[a-z0-9A-Z.-]+`.